How to prevent shadows from highly metallic principled BSDF despite turning them off? (Cycles)
I have a plane with a material I like.

However, despite turning off the shadows of the other meshes via the object properties, I still see a shadow/(reflection?). How can I turn it off? and why is it still casting a shadow?



Is it a shadow or a reflection? To turn off visibility in reflections, disable Glossy. But when you turn off the meshes being reflected on the plane, then I doubt the Metallic part will still contribute much to make the material look good.
